# How to rename file in branch, merge and have two files with history in Git?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a git repository with the following branches:

```
older:
    file (with, say, 10 commits)

newer:
    file (10 commits  from "older" plus 5 new commits)
```

Branch "newer" was branched from branch "older" as some point.

I would like to merge both branches into master, have both versions of "file" as two different files and I want to keep history for both:

```
master:
    file-as-seen-in-older (10 commits)
    file-as-seen-in-newer (15 commits)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a robust and safe way to change the file name, using `git rebase`. This will work perfectly in the simple case where your branch `newer` and/or `older` diverged from master (or some other branch), and did not merge in new changes from the parent branch after that — removing the old file name completely from your history.

(If such merges did occur, then the command is still safe — and the end result is the same — but it might not clean up your history as far back as you would like.)

1. Choose which branch you want to change the file-name in. Checkout that branch. I'll assume you picked `older`.

   ```
   $ git checkout older
   ```
2. Now, we need to find the *merge base* of `older` and its parent. This is where `older` diverges from its parent, creating a new, independent history. You can normally find this out easily by browsing `git log`  or `gitk`, but we can find it with a simple command. (I'll assume `master` is the parent of `older`.)

   ```
   $ git merge-base older master
   914b05d90e1de0ff9f89370810888c7f192d65cc
   $ git tag base 914b05d
   ```

   In my repository, `git merge-base` output the commit id `914b05d`. We label the commit with the tag `base` for easy reference.
3. Now, do an interactive rebase onto `base`

   ```
   $ git rebase --interactive base
   ```
4. In the editor window that shows up, verify that it lists every commit in older, from the time that it diverged from its parent, until the latest commit.

   - Move to the first commit.
   - Change the word `pick` to `edit`. We will soon edit this commit to rename the file.
   - Now, look down through the other commits. Any that mention the name `file`  in the commit message will need to be reworded. Change `pick` to `reword` to give yourself the chance to reword the appropriate commit messages.
   - Save the file and exit.
5. Now, your rebase will begin! git will checkout the first commit and stop, waiting for you to amend the commit. Here, we can move the file, and begin the rebase again.

   ```
    $ git mv file file-from-older
    $ git rebase --continue
   ```

   git will amend the commit with your changes, and then open your editor to allow you to reword the commit. Change any references to `file` to say `file-from-older` instead. Save the file and exit.
6. Any commits which you marked for `reword`ing will also come up in your editor. Edit them in the same fashion. *(If you missed marking a commit for rewording, you can rebase again)*
7. Once the rebase finishes, examine the result, with `git log`, or `gitk`. Observe that

   - The original file name does not exist in your working tree
   - or in your history, and that
   - `older` still branches from its parent at the same place, namely `base`.

   *If any of these things is untrue, something went wrong (maybe a typo), and we need to undo the commit. We can do that easily with `git reset --hard older@{1}`, which resets older to its state just before the rebase occurred. You can then repeat the rebase operation, and figure out where it went wrong.*
8. Now that you've verified the success of the rebase, you can merge your changes into `master`, or wherever. If you want to rename `file` in both branches, simply repeat the process for the `newer` branch as well.
9. Finally, you can merge your branches into `master`:

   ```
   $ git checkout master
   $ git merge older newer
   ```

   Baring any (unrelated) conflicts, this should go smoothly.